# Apply comma to number field in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, numbers, number-formatting

I have a column that contains numbers.  Is it possible to make the numbers appear with a comma on Server-Side with a function? or do I need to this on the client side with a php script?  I would prefer server-side.

Comment: PHP is ran on the server, not the client.

Comment: Presentational issues don't really belong in the database layer...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just use MySQL's [`FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_format) function

```
mysql> SELECT FORMAT(12332.123456, 4);
        -> '12,332.1235'
mysql> SELECT FORMAT(12332.1,4);
        -> '12,332.1000'
mysql> SELECT FORMAT(12332.2,0);
        -> '12,332'
mysql> SELECT FORMAT(12332.2,2,'de_DE');
        -> '12.332,20'
```

Or PHP's [`number_format()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
<?php

$number = 1234.56;

// english notation (default)
$english_format_number = number_format($number);
// 1,235

// French notation
$nombre_format_francais = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');
// 1 234,56

$number = 1234.5678;

// english notation without thousands separator
$english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
// 1234.57

?>
```