# Not able to import price column properly in MySQL from a CSV file

Tags: mysql

I've a csv file containing data in this format:

```
SATURN,6459,"50,486",27184
```

I'm using this command to import this file into the table:

```
 LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:\\temp.csv' INTO TABLE `test`.`tmp` FIELDS ESCAPED BY '\\'
 TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'   
 (`description`,`file_no`,`net`,`run_no`);
```

all the fields are being imported correctly but the **net** column always having the data like

```
 50.00 // it should be 50,486
```

Data type of this column is Decimal(10,2). I've also tried Numeric(10,2) but no luck. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a try with this one:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:\\temp.csv' INTO TABLE `test`.`tmp` FIELDS ESCAPED BY '\\'
TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'   
(`description`, `file_no`, @a_variable, `run_no`)
SET `net` = REPLACE(@a_variable, ',', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL cannot deal with commas as 1000 separators when inserting numbers. You need to parse out these commas before loading.

If you need the numbers formatted this way when querying, use FORMAT(). For examples see [Apply comma to number field in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744437/apply-comma-to-number-field-in-mysql)

Comment: is there any way to replace any comma inside a field while importing CSV files?